# "Generalized eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent" for infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

This is form Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.
Please allow me to borrow the screenshot from [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349965/generalized-eigenvectors-are-linearly-independent) :
[8.13 Linearly independent generalized eigenvectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tynFk.png)

From the above picture, we can see that in the proof of 8.13 the author uses the condition "V is finite-dimensional".

My question is that, if V is an infinite-dimensional space, does this conclusion still hold?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1,\cdots,v_m$ are generalized eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_m$, then the subspace
\begin{equation}
W = \text{span}\{T^i v_j: i\in{\mathbb N}, j\in\{1,\cdots,m\}\} 
\end{equation}
is finite dimensional and stable by $T$. The $v_j$'s are generalized eigenvectors of the restriction of $T$ to $W$, hence the theorem applies and they are linearly independent.

That said, the spectral properties of operators in infinite dimensional spaces are not limited to just eigenvalues, eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I haven't understood the process yet, but I learned that the conclusion is still correct.